# Using Xbuild with Xamarin.Android (formerly Mono for Android)

Tags: jenkins, xamarin.android, xamarin, xbuild

We have a Xamarin.Android project that we are trying to build using Jenkins on a Mac. The Solution file contains several different projects, one of which is the MonoDroid project. The MonoDroid Project is dependent upon the other projects in the solution.

The problem that I have is that when I use `xbuild` to build the solution file, I have no way to use the /t:PackageForAndroid target, since it only is valid for the MD Project File.

Currently in Jenkins, I'm doing it like this:

```
xbuild MyCoolDroidAp/MyCoolDroidApp.sln /p:Configuration=Release /t:Clean
xbuild MyCoolDroidApp/MyCoolDroidApp.sln /p:Configuration=Release /t:Build
xbuild MyCoolDroidApp/MyCoolDroidProject.csproj /p:Configuration=Release /t:PackageForAndroid
```

This is working, but it seems to me that there should be a way to eliminate the 3rd step. Does anyone have any insight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The consensus around the interwebs seems to be that I am doing this the right way.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use Xamarin.Studio/MonoDevelop to sign & zipalign your APK, you can do that at the command line. I've had luck using [rake to compile, sign, and zipalign my APK files](https://gist.github.com/topgenorth/5094153). Would something like that work for you?

Failing that, here is a simple Powershell script that you could probably port over real easy:

```
# First clean the Release target.
msbuild.exe HelloWorld.csproj /p:Configuration=Release /t:Clean

# Now build the project, using the Release target.
msbuild.exe HelloWorld.csproj /p:Configuration=Release /t:PackageForAndroid

# At this point there is only the unsigned APK - sign it.
# The script will pause here as jarsigner prompts for the password.
# It is possible to provide they keystore password for jarsigner.exe by adding an extra command line parameter -storepass, for example
#    -storepass <MY_SECRET_PASSWORD>
# If this script is to be checked in to source code control then it is not recommended to include the password as part of this script.
& 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_24\bin\jarsigner.exe' -verbose -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1  -keystore ./xample.keystore -signedjar 
./bin/Release/mono.samples.helloworld-signed.apk 
./bin/Release/mono.samples.helloworld.apk publishingdoc

# Now zipalign it.  The -v parameter tells zipalign to verify the APK afterwards.
& 'C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools\zipalign.exe' -f -v 4
./bin/Release/mono.samples.helloworld-signed.apk ./helloworld.apk
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: So I've tried this, but using xbuild instead of msbuild. My problem is at the 2nd step ... there are projects in the solution upon which the MonoDroid project is dependent. When I call xbuild on the .csproj file, those dependent solutions do not get built.

Comment: I am doing the signing and zip alignment outside of the xbuild process -- they are subsequent steps in Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Signing your apk i'm using something like this as a part of my makefile and it works ok:

```
...

BUILD_DIR = ./builds/$(platform)
KEYSTORE_PATH = your_keystore_pass
STORE_PASS = your_keystore_pass
ANDROID_SDK_PATH = path/to/your/android/sdk/dir 
#example ANDROID_SDK_PATH = /Developer/AndroidSDK
RES_APK = my_apk.apk
APK_NAME = my_signed_apk.apk

...


sign:
  (cd $(BUILD_DIR); jarsigner -verbose -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore $(KEYSTORE_PATH) -storepass $(STORE_PASS) result.apk $(STORE_PASS))
  (cd $(BUILD_DIR); $(ANDROID_SDK_PATH)/tools/zipalign -v 4 result.apk $(APK_NAME))
  (cd $(BUILD_DIR);rm result.apk)
  (cd $(BUILD_DIR);rm $(RES_APK))
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I did something similar in jenkins with jar signer and zip align.